# Azure App Gateway - Backend Health 404 error

Tags: azure, adfs, azure-application-gateway, adfs3.0

I am trying to configure Azure Application Gateway with ADFS. The Backend pool points to ADFS Web Application Proxy. The backend health check is reporting as unhealthy.
I am getting an a error: received invalid status code 404 in the backend servers http response

Everything appears to be configured correctly and I can access the site when bypassing the App Gateway

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by re-configuring the health probe

Answer (score 0):

In my case with the App Service as a backend pool, I had to create a custom Health probe(`http-probe` for ex.) to be used in the HTTP setting(`http` for ex.), where the HTTP setting(`http` for ex.) is the one configured in the Request Routing Rule.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]